# System.TypeException: Methods defined as TestMethod do not support Web service callouts, test skipped

Tags: unit-test, httpcalloutmock

we have written trigger for echo-sign object, after updating object through our trigger, echo-sign code calls @future method from their managed package. this future method has webservice callout.
Our trigger working perfect but while writing test call it is failing and throw out exception as:

> FATAL_ERROR System.TypeException: Methods defined as TestMethod do not
>   support Web service callouts, test skipped

In test class I tried with mock http call (i come to know form several post here on stackoverflow) as below:

```
System.runAs(loggedUser) 
    {               
        Test.startTest();
        Test.setMock(HttpCalloutMock.class, new MockHttpResponseGenerator());
        List<echosign_dev1__SIGN_AgreementEvent__c> agreeEventList = new List<echosign_dev1__SIGN_AgreementEvent__c>();
        List<echosign_dev1__SIGN_AgreementEvent__c> events = TestData_Obj.getechosigndev1SIGN_AgreementEventList(listSize);
        List<echosign_dev1__SIGN_Agreement__c> echoAgreementList = TestData_Obj.getEchosign_dev1_SIGN_AgreementList(listSize);
        insert echoAgreementList;
         for(integer i = 0; i<listSize; i++) {
            echosign_dev1__SIGN_AgreementEvent__c agreementEvent = events.get(i);
            agreementEvent.echosign_dev1__SIGN_Agreement__c = echoAgreementList.get(i).id;
            agreeEventList.add(agreementEvent);
        }
        try{
            insert agreeEventList;  
        } catch(Exception e) {
            system.debug(e.getMessage());
        }
        Test.stopTest();
    }
```

but its not working.
How i overcome with this error?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you sure there's no other test that inserts or updates echo-sign objects, in which you haven't specified the mock?

Comment: Thanks @Lex, we have created only 1 test class where we are inserting echo-sign object. no other places i found it. I observed that error occur after system.Test.stopTest(). I just tried my luck with setMock, but it is not working and it throwing same error; even i added try-catch statement around to insert echoObj;

Comment: Could you share the entire test method?

Comment: @Lex please have a look at updated post

Comment: I can't find a problem in your code. Are you a 100% sure this is where the fatal error occurs?

Comment: @Lex fatal error occurs after stoptest method in echosign object

Comment: This is really old post, but maybe some had solved this problem?